# Is it possible to pass HTML through a PHP function's acceptable parameters?

Tags: php

This doesn't work:

```
$F = "<div class='f'>F</div>";
$d = "<div class='d'>d</div>";
$Y = "<div class='y'>Y</div>";

$dateFormat = "$F, $d, $Y";

echo date($dateFormat);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What you have posted will absolutely not work, it would require the date() function to understand HTML.

Comment: This question makes no sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date()` will not filter out the HTML tags from the parameter you pass; that is the case of many other PHP functions to which you pass a string containing HTML tags.
The only function that removes HTML tags is `strip_tags()`. If, for any reason, you are using as parameter of a function a string containing HTML (I don't know in which case it could happen — maybe you are doing something wrong in other parts of the code), you can use the following code, valid for the example you reported.

```
$F = strip_tags("<div class='f'>F</div>");
$d = strip_tags("<div class='d'>d</div>");
$Y = strip_tags("<div class='y'>Y</div>");

$dateFormat = "$F, $d, $Y";

echo date($dateFormat);
```

This is the answer to your question. Probably your problem is another one; in that case, the question should have been another one.
I think there are some chances that Sbm007 understood what you meant; the question should have been then

> How do I insert HTML tags in a date formatted with `date()`?
>
> I am trying to format a date mixed in with some HTML.
>   I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work:
>
> `$F = strip_tags("<div class='f'>F</div>");`
>   `$d = strip_tags("<div class='d'>d</div>");`
>   `$Y = strip_tags("<div class='y'>Y</div>");`
>
> `$dateFormat = "$F, $d, $Y";`
>   `echo date($dateFormat);`

Comment: Interesting interpretation of the question.

Comment: I just tried to give a sense to something apparently without any sense. `;-)`